# Why doesn't C++ like this syntax for strings?

Tags: c++, string, resize, assign

```
name_abbreviation = name_last.resize(2);
```

Here I have to assign first

```
name_abbreviation = name_last;
```

Then

```
name_abbreviation.resize(2);
```

Would like to kindly ask you if you could explain me why the other way doesn't work?

Comment: `string::resize()` returns nothing (return value is void). you cannot assign its return value to a string.

Comment: Make sure you read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) carefully. Namely "*Resizes the string to contain count characters. [...] **Return value** (none)*"

Comment: @scohe001 OP does not want to assign result of `resize()` read question more carefully.

Comment: @Slava Isn't that exactly what OP wants? `name_abbreviation = name_last.resize(2);` sure looks like it.

Comment: @Slava I'm not sure why you assume that that's what I've said. But regardless, does the documentation I've posted not answer their question of "why the other way doesn't work?"

Comment: @TedLyngmo wha OP wants is achived by 2 statements  - assignment first and then by `name_abbreviation.resize(2);` so I do not think so.

Comment: @scohe001 no it does not, because problem for OP is not that `resize()` returns nothing, but that `resize()` is called on the wrong object. At least how I understood his question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because due to operator precedence this code:

```
name_abbreviation = name_last.resize(2);
```

is equal to:

```
name_abbreviation = (name_last.resize(2));
```

and is logically equal to:

```
auto tmp = name_last.resize(2);
name_abbreviation = tmp;
```

which is not compilable as `std::string::resize()` returns nothing and even if it would compile it would not do what you want.

What you want to do can be achieved by:

```
(name_abbreviation = name_last).resize(2);
```

but this not quite readable code. I, personally, would prefer 2 separate statements.

Note the same result can be achieved by much simpler code:

```
name_abbreviation = name_last.substr( 0, 2 );
```

which can be also more efficient on some implementations.

Comment: I tried first to do name_abbreviation = (name_last.resize(2)); thanks for the explanation @Slava. Would this be bad if you code like that, even if it makes the code more compact?

Comment: @LIT readability is subjective obviously, it does not fill right to me this way, but some people may find it perfectly fine.

Comment: An alternative if you know you have at least 2 characters in the original string and don't want to copy a lot of characters that you discard right away: `name_abbreviation = std::string(name_last.begin(), name_last.begin() + 2);`

Comment: @TedLyngmo is this useful if you want to safe processing speed?

Comment: @LIT It's microoptimization and rarely noticable - but if you process a huge amount of large strings it'll be good. If you are not sure you have at least 2 chars, you could do `name_abbreviation = std::string(name_last.begin(), name_last.begin() + std::min(name_last.size(), static_cast<size_t>(2)));`. Note that the result will then be max 2 chars, but shorter if the original is shorter. It'll be even quicker if you do it at construction: `std::string name_abbreviation(name_last.begin(), name_last.begin() + std::min(name_last.size(), static_cast<size_t>(2)));`

Comment: @TedLyngmo you wrote quite long equivalent of `substr( 0, 2 );` :)

Comment: @Slava Indeed. The first: `name_abbreviation = std::string(name_last.begin(), name_last.begin() + std::min(name_last.size(), static_cast<size_t>(2)));` is probably compiled into the same thing as `substr()`. If it's done at construction, and construction only needs to be done once, it _may_ be a little cheaper than `substr` but it would need to be measured properly ... overkill :-)

Answer (score 1):

`resize()` function doesn't return a thing. It changes the size of allocated memory of the string it use on it. So to assign a string to another just use

```
name_abbreviation = name_last;
```

using the operator `=` will make the string on the L.H.S. have the same size of the string on the right and have the same characters..